# How to switch viewpager Tab with button Click in Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-viewpager, android-tablayout

I want to switch Fragments by button click inside the fragment itself. I have have created viewpager + tablayout, everything worked until i made an interface to communicate with my activity where i can set different Page for Viewpager. I am pretty new to Kotlin and I do not understand why I am catching NullPointer :(
I probably initialized my button poorly too, but I am not sure

**Here is my MainActivity code**

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity()
, MyFragment1.buttonClick {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fragment1))
    tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fragment_2))
    tablayout.addTab(tablayout.newTab().setIcon(R.drawable.ic_fragment3))
    tablayout.tabGravity = TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL

    val adapter = MyAdapter(this, supportFragmentManager, tablayout.tabCount)
    viewpager!!.adapter = adapter

    viewpager.addOnPageChangeListener(TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tablayout))


    val tabStrip = tablayout.getChildAt(0) as LinearLayout
    for (i in 0 until tabStrip.childCount) {
        tabStrip.getChildAt(i).setOnTouchListener { v, event -> true }
    }
}


override fun buttonClicked(view: View) {
    viewpager.currentItem = 2
}

fun selectIndex(index: Int) {
    viewpager.currentItem = index
}

override fun onBackPressed() {
    val currentPos = viewpager.currentItem
    if (currentPos != 0) {
        viewpager.currentItem = 0
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed()
    }
}
}



**And a code for my Fragment**



 class MyFragment1 : Fragment() {

private  var click: buttonClick? = null

interface buttonClick {
    fun buttonClicked(view: View)
}

var currentPage: Int = 0


override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {

    val view: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_fragment1, container, false)
    val btn: Button = view?.findViewById(R.id.btn_next)

    btn.setOnClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(context, "test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        click?.buttonClicked(it)

    }

    return view
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you initialized your `click` variable?

```
private var click: buttonClick? = null

override fun onAttach(context: Context?) {
    super.onAttach(context)
    click = context as? buttonClick
}

override fun onDetach() {
    super.onDetach()
    click = null
}
```

Comment: nice, yeah I did